# Go file read performance looks strange between Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, file, go, system-calls

### Here is the code (main.go)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func read(accumulatorSize, readBufSize int) {
    buf := make([]byte, readBufSize)
    f, _ := os.Open("dump.txt")
    defer f.Close()
    var n int64
    var took time.Duration

    start := time.Now()
    for {
        delta, err := f.Read(buf)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        n += int64(delta)
        if n >= int64(accumulatorSize) {
            break
        }
    }
    took = time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Read: read buffer size %d, read total %d, took %v\n", readBufSize, n, took)
}

func main() {
    MB := 1024 * 1024
    KB := 1024
    FILESIZE := 100 * MB
    read(FILESIZE, 1*KB)
    read(FILESIZE, 512*KB)
}
```

### Results (go run main.go)

#### Windows

Read: read buffer size 1024, read total 104857600, took 201.3612ms

Read: read buffer size 524288, read total 104857600, took 15.792ms

#### Linux (a wsl2 backend container)

Read: read buffer size 1024, read total 104857600, took 17.092969328s

Read: read buffer size 524288, read total 104857600, took 120.544513ms

##### Also tried pprof in Linux

[pprof result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Dvm.png)

It seems that the time pprof have recorded mush short than actual runing time.

### I want to know

1. The reason these results vary so much.
2. Will pprof stop recording when process in status sleep?

Comment: "I want to know the reason these results vary so much." Because virtualization isn't free.

Comment: aside from this only measuring syscall time in wsl2, you're use of `Read` would be incorrect if you wanted to use the data. You must account for bytes read before checking for `io.EOF` (or use `bufio` or the  `io` helpers to do the low level reads for you)

Comment: that make sense, tried on a native linux machine, everything works fine. didn't realized that system calls are so expensive in the case of virtualization. thanks a lot @Peter